# JavaScript Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, scope

I'm having a problem with some JavaScript code.

**Script**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        }, i * 200);
    }
}, 200);
```

**Outputs**

5, 5, 5, 5, 5 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

I can kind of understand why this doesn't work, but I was wondering if someone could explain to me what's happening and why it's not working!

Also, how can this scope problem be overcome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setTimeout` callback functions are executed asynchronously, all the `console.log` calls you make refer to the same `i` variable, and at the time they are executed, the for loop *has ended* and `i` contains 4.

You could wrap your inner `setTimeout` call inside a function accepting a parameter in order to store a reference to all the `i` values that are being iterated, something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      (function (j) { // added a closure to store a reference to 'i' values
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(j);
        }, j * 200);
      })(i); // automatically call the function and pass the value
    }
}, 200);
```

Check my answer to the following question for more details:

- [Variables in Anonymous Functions — Can someone explain the following?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941)

Comment: Thanks for your response and your answer on that other question! It explained it all perfectly!

Comment: @bdukes: rolled back edit, the last value of `i` is `4`, notice the `i < 5` condition on the for loop.

Comment: i will be 5 - that's the value that terminates the loop (and is also the value reported by the OP)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/variables-in-anonymous-functions-can-someone-explain-the-following).  It might help you understand the scope and closures better, very similar to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the great link! It explains it perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to create a closure containing the variable "i". But closures are only created at the end of a function. So if your functions are created in a **for** loop, they will all have the values from the last iteration.

You can fix it with something like this:

```
var createFunction = function(index) {
  return function() {
    console.log(index);
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(createFunction(i), i * 200);
}
```

where you return the function from another function.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` exists in the scope of the outer function.

It changes as the loop runs.

The inner function references it.

Try something like this:

```
var i_print_factory = function (value) {
  return function () {
    console.log(value);
  };
};

var init_timers = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(i_print_factory(i), i * 200);
  }
};

setTimeout(init_timers, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are accessing the same variable i in all the functions used in set timeout.  The setTimeout function sets the function to fire the number of milliseconds in the future on the same thread as the i variable.  The i value isn't copied in the function, the function is referencing the actual variable i when it is fired. Because you have looped through parent function until the i = 5 and this is done before anything else has a chance to fire, they all show up as 5.