# Very strange behavior with assigning methods in a loop

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Consider this code below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(-1)" id="a1">a1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(-1)" id="a2">a2</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var buttons = []
    buttons.push("a1")
    buttons.push("a2")
    var actions = []
    for (var i in buttons)
    {
        actions[buttons[i]] = function() { alert(i) }
    }

    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    for (var k = 0; k < elements.length; k++)
    {
        elements[k].onclick = actions[elements[k].id]
    }
    
</script>
```

Basically, it shows two anchors, a1 and a2, and I expect to see "1" and "2" popping up in an alert when clicking on corresponding anchor.
It doesn't happen, I get "2" when clicking on either. After spending an hour meditating on the code, I decided that it probably happens because dynamic `onclick` methods for both anchors keep the last value of "i".
So I changed that loop to:

```
for (var i in buttons)
{
    var local_i = i.toString()
    actions[buttons[i]] = function() { alert(local_i) }
}
```

hoping that each dynamic function will get its own copy of "i" with immediate value. But after this change I get "1" popping up when I click on either link.

What am I doing wrong? It's a huge show-stopper for me.

Comment: Possible dupes that I have answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579978/

Comment: +1 Exactly the same problem as those you answered in those two posts

Comment: I hope you noticed my last edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last value is stored, you can use closures for this:

```
<a  href="#">blah</a><br>
<a  href="#">blah</a><br>
<a  href="#">foo</a><br>

<script>
    (function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for ( var i = anchors.length; i--; ) {
        var link = anchors[i];
        (function(i) {
            link.onclick = function() {
                alert(i)
            }
        })(i);
    }
    })();
</script>
```

This solution binds the `i` to the function scope, the key trick is the executing of the function inside of the loop, otherwise you are left with the end result of iterating through and alerting the last value of `i`.

Reference: http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html

Comment: But I don't understand, why it doesn't bind local_i to the function scope, as I tried in the second example?

Comment: You need to execute a function inside of the loop in order for this to work.

Comment: @Andrey - because Javascript does not have block level scoping, only function level scoping.  When you declare a variable in a function, using var, it's scope to that function, even if it is inside a for loop.  By doing what meder has above, you create a new scope.

Answer (score 2):

This [blog post](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) explains the problem pretty well. The thing is that loops doesn't have their own variable scopes in JavaScript, so the inner function is using the scope of the parent function.

Answer (score -1):

Don’t use `for (… in …)` for arrays. Use the simple `for` loop instead:

```
for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i) {
    actions[buttons[i]] = (function(i) {
        return function() {
            alert(i);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: But the point remains. +1. It could have been a comment though.

Comment: How is it a +1? 
How "for (var i = 0 ...)"  is better than  "for (var i in ...)"?
For me, it's all syntax sugar - am I wrong?

Comment: @Andrey: The `for...in ` statement is meant to be used to iterate *object properties*, the problem with this statement is that it crawls up the prototype chain, and if the `Array.prototype` has been extended, those extensions will be iterated also (if you don't use hasOwnProperty) and also, this statement doesn't ensure anyhow the order of iteration.

Comment: I see your point. Unfortunately it does't let me remove my down vote - "vote is too old".