# " document.getElementById onmouseover and function " does not behave as wished × 108641

Tags: javascript

In this function, it should give the menu items (li's) an specific background (png) out of an array. However; it doesn't. It gives all the li's the background called color 'blue' :(.
Do you see the problem?

```
//Gives the menu items a style when hovering over it, in the sequence of the setting in the variable 'backgrounds', on top.
var backgrounds = ["blue", "green", "pink", "purple"];

function MenuColorChange() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++) {
        document.getElementById("custom-menu-item-id-" + (i + 1)).onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.backgroundImage= "url(images/" +  backgrounds[(i % backgrounds.length)] + ".png)";
        }
        document.getElementById("custom-menu-item-id-" + (i + 1)).onmouseout = function() {
        this.style.background = 'none'; 
        MenuActiveColor();
        }
    }
}
```

Html:

```
        <ul>
            <li id="custom-menu-item-id-1">
                <a href="#">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
                            /* And 3 li's more... */
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you use for `onmouseover` is a closuse of the outer function, in the time it is executed all `onmouseover` handlers have the save value of `i`, to achieve what you seen to want do:

```
//Gives the menu items a style when hovering over it, in the sequence of the setting in the variable 'backgrounds', on top.
var backgrounds = ["blue", "green", "pink", "purple"];
function MenuColorChange() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++) {
        document.getElementById("custom-menu-item-id-" + (i + 1)).onmouseover = (function(valueOfI){ return function() {
        this.style.backgroundImage= "url(images/" +  backgrounds[(valueOfI % backgrounds.length)] + ".png)";
        }; })(i);
        document.getElementById("custom-menu-item-id-" + (i + 1)).onmouseout = function() {
        this.style.background = 'none'; 
        MenuActiveColor();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This surprises me. I would expect it to make all the backgrounds pink. The reason this happens is because by the time you actually hover over any of your `<li>` elements, `i` will be `10`, and `10 % 4 = 2`. Index #2 of your array is `'pink'`.

To ensure that `i` is the value you want when the *mouseover* and *mouseout* events are fired, wrap them in a function.

```
function MenuColorChange() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            document.getElementById("custom-menu-item-id-" + (i + 1)).onmouseover = function() {
                this.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/" +  backgrounds[(i % backgrounds.length)] + ".png)";
            }
            document.getElementById("custom-menu-item-id-" + (i + 1)).onmouseout = function() {
                this.style.background = 'none'; 
                MenuActiveColor();
            }
        }(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation that may help: [variables-in-anonymous-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/variables-in-anonymous-functions-can-someone-explain-the-following)