# Nonworking function as soon as page loading

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

There is a Youtube chromeless Javascript player in [demo](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/). Unless user clicks playlist pictures below player, title and time don't shown. To show title and time user has to click some playlist image or has to wait cahanging to the next video. I want title and time to be written without clicking anything after first video autoload. There might be a problem javascript function order. Nothing comes to my mind apart from this.

All codes are below to help next people in future

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" lang="en"/>
<title>title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2/swfobject.js"></script>  

</head>
<body> 


<div class="ikinciSol">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="play();">Play</a>
                -
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="pause();">Pause</a>
                -
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="stop();">Stop</a>
                <div id="videoTime">
                    <span id="videoCurrentTime"></span>
                    <span id="videoDuration"></span>
                </div>
                <div id="ytplayer_status"></div>
                <a name="ytplayer"></a>
<div id="ytplayer">You need Flash player 10+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>
<div id="ytplayer_div2"></div>


  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  //
  // YouTube JavaScript API Player With Playlist
  // http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2009/10/youtube-javascript-player-with-playlist.html
  // Revision 2 [2012-03-24]
  //
  // Prerequisites
  // 1) Create following elements in your HTML:
  // -- a) ytplayer: a named anchor
  // -- b) ytplayer_div1: placeholder div for YouTube JavaScript Player
  // -- c) ytplayer_div2: container div for playlist
  // 2) Include SWFObject library from http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/
  //
  // Variables
  // -- ytplayer_playlist: an array containing YouTube Video IDs
  // -- ytplayer_playitem: index of the video to be played at any given time
  //
  var ytplayer_playlist = [ ];
  var ytplayer_playitem = 0;
  swfobject.addLoadEvent( ytplayer_render_player );
  swfobject.addLoadEvent( ytplayer_render_playlist );
  function ytplayer_render_player( )
  {
     swfobject.embedSWF
    (
      'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?video_id='+ ytplayer_playlist[ ytplayer_playitem ].videoid + '&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&version=3&rel=0&fs=1&playerapiid=ytplayer',
      'ytplayer',
      '400',
      '225',
      '10',
      null,
      null,
      {
        allowScriptAccess: 'always',
        allowFullScreen: 'true'
      },
      {
        id: 'ytplayer'
      }
    );

  }

    // Update a particular HTML element with a new value
    function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
      var elem = document.getElementById(elmId);
      if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
        document.getElementById(elmId).innerHTML = value;
      }
    }

//Converting seconds minute:second
function secondsToHms(d) {
d = Number(d);
var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" : "") + (m > 0 ? (h > 0 && m < 10 ? "0" : "") + m + ":" : "0:") + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s); }


// Display information about the current state of the player
function updatePlayerInfo() {
    // Also check that at least one function exists since when IE unloads the
    // page, it will destroy the SWF before clearing the interval.
    if(ytplayer && ytplayer.getDuration) {
        updateHTML("videoCurrentTime", secondsToHms(ytplayer.getCurrentTime())+' /');
        updateHTML("videoDuration", secondsToHms(ytplayer.getDuration()));
        updateHTML("bytesTotal", ytplayer.getVideoBytesTotal());
        updateHTML("startBytes", ytplayer.getVideoStartBytes());
        updateHTML("bytesLoaded", ytplayer.getVideoBytesLoaded());
        updateHTML("volume", ytplayer.getVolume());
    }
}

  function ytplayer_render_playlist( )
  {
    for ( var i = 0; i < ytplayer_playlist.length; i++ )
    {
      var img = document.createElement( "img" );
      img.src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ytplayer_playlist[ i ].videoid + "/default.jpg";
      var a = document.createElement( "a" );
      a.href = "#ytplayer";
      //
      // Thanks to some nice people who answered this question:
      // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/variables-in-anonymous-functions-can-someone-explain-the-following
      //
      a.onclick = (
        function( j )
        {
          return function( )
          {
            ytplayer_playitem = j;
            ytplayer_playlazy( 1000 );
          };
        }
      )( i );
      a.appendChild( img );
      document.getElementById( "ytplayer_div2" ).appendChild( a );
    }
  }
  function ytplayer_playlazy( delay )
  {
    //
    // Thanks to the anonymous person posted this tip:
    // http://www.tipstrs.com/tip/1084/Static-variables-in-Javascript
    //
    if ( typeof ytplayer_playlazy.timeoutid != 'undefined' )
    {
      window.clearTimeout( ytplayer_playlazy.timeoutid );
    }
    ytplayer_playlazy.timeoutid = window.setTimeout( ytplayer_play, delay );
  }
  function ytplayer_play( )
  {
    var o = document.getElementById( 'ytplayer' );
    if ( o )
    {
      o.loadVideoById( ytplayer_playlist[ ytplayer_playitem ].videoid );
      document.getElementById( "ytplayer_status" ).innerHTML = ytplayer_playlist[ ytplayer_playitem ].title;
      setInterval(updatePlayerInfo, 250);

    }
  }
  //
  // Ready Handler (this function is called automatically by YouTube JavaScript Player when it is ready)
  // * Sets up handler for other events
  //
  function onYouTubePlayerReady( playerid )
  {
    var o = document.getElementById( 'ytplayer' );
    if ( o )
    {
      o.addEventListener( "onStateChange", "ytplayerOnStateChange" );
      o.addEventListener( "onError", "ytplayerOnError" );
    }
  }
  //
  // State Change Handler
  // * Sets up the video index variable
  // * Calls the lazy play function
  //
  function ytplayerOnStateChange( state )
  {
    if ( state == 0 )
    {
      ytplayer_playitem += 1;
      ytplayer_playitem %= ytplayer_playlist.length;
      ytplayer_playlazy( 1000 );
    }
  }
  //
  // Error Handler
  // * Sets up the video index variable
  // * Calls the lazy play function
  //
  function ytplayerOnError( error )
  {
    if ( error )
    {
      ytplayer_playitem += 1;
      ytplayer_playitem %= ytplayer_playlist.length;
      ytplayer_playlazy( 1000 );
    }
  }
  //
  // Add items to the playlist one-by-one
  //
  ytplayer_playlist.push( 
  {
      videoid: 'tGvHNNOLnCk',
      title: 'title1'
  } 
  );
    ytplayer_playlist.push( 
  {
      videoid: '_-8IufkbuD0',
      title: 'title2'
  } 
  );
    ytplayer_playlist.push( 
  {
      videoid: 'wvsboPUjrGc',
      title: "title3"
  } 
  );
    ytplayer_playlist.push( 
  {
      videoid: '8To-6VIJZRE',
      title: 'title4'
  } 
  );
    ytplayer_playlist.push( 
  {
      videoid: '8pdkEJ0nFBg',
      title: 'title5'
  } 
  );



function play() {

  if (ytplayer) {

    document.getElementById('ytplayer').playVideo();

  }

}



function pause() {

  if (ytplayer) {

    document.getElementById('ytplayer').pauseVideo();

  }

}



function stop() {

  if (ytplayer) {

    document.getElementById('ytplayer').stopVideo();

  }

}


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't include :

`document.getElementById( "ytplayer_status" ).innerHTML = ytplayer_playlist[ ytplayer_playitem ].title;`

in  your update function like shown below, the changes I have done are :

- I added the set title function to the update function.
- I added the setTimeout update function to body onload event
- Take out the set title and timeout from `ytplayer_play`

Here is the correction :

http://jsfiddle.net/KpTaA/1/