# Send a XHR when user "completes" the input instead of keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The HTML code: `<input id="goTOxQuestion">`
The js code:

```
$("#goTOxQuestion").keyup(function(){
    // send a XHR
})
```

If the input is `12345`,it will send the XHR five times.
In fact, I only want the XHR be executed when I have completed the input. I mean,there is no input( no keydown event ）in 500 milliseconds, rather then it loses faocus.
My incomplete solution:

```
var isOver = false;
$("#goTOxQuestion").keyup(function(){
    //...
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(isOver){
            //send a XHR
        }
    },500);
})
$("#goTOxQuestion").keydown(function(){
    isOver = false;
})
```

Comment: If a pop up from another webpage show up then it's possible that the  input's blur event will trigger which is not an expected behavior. You need to use a button for this, if you want your user to have a good experience with your site.

Comment: @Arun I don't do it like that, sorry.

Comment: ok, then what is your question here, your code seem to be correct, what error you are getting ?

Comment: @RickyStam yes,you are right,I stand with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of setTimeout and clearTimeout like this:

```
var hTimeout;
$("#goTOxQuestion").keyup(function () {
    if (hTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(hTimeout);
    }
    hTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        // ajax code here
    }, 500);
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4eXv/1/)

Note that the order in which AJAX requests complete is not guaranteed and you will end up with "race conditions".

---

Regarding your comment, here is a solution from the top of my mind:

```
// initialize global counter
var xhrCount = 0;
// increment counter when you create an XHR
xhrCount++;
// pass the current value of this
// variable to the success function
// http://stackoverflow.com/q/1552941/87015
$.ajax("/url/", (function (myStamp) {
    console.log("creating success callback #" + myStamp);
    return function () {
        if (myStamp === xhrCount) {
            console.log("firing success handler");
        } else {
            console.log("suppressing success handler");
        }
    }
})(xhrCount));
```

Comment: Note that the order in which AJAX requests complete is not guaranteed....I need the last request.thanks

Comment: Detecting if the request was the last one could be a pita. You can try (i) declaring a global counter (ii) increment the counter when AJAX is created (iii) in the success function, compare the current request's number with global counter.

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout then:

```
$("#goTOxQuestion").keyup(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // send a XHR
    }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: Here is a corresponding fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m4ABn/8/ It works, but calls alert a couple of times in the end :S

Answer (score 1):

The [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) seems like a good fit for your needs :

```
$("#goTOxQuestion").change(function(){
    // send a XHR
})
```

It will be triggered when the input looses focus *and* the input value was actually modified.

Comment: The event is deferred until the element loses focus.I want the request be sended when I have completed the input ,rather then it lose loses faocus.

Comment: Could you please explain `when I have completed the input` ?

Comment: oh,I am sorry ,no input（keydown event ）in 500 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('blur',"#goTOxQuestion",function(){
    // send a XHR
});
```