# gmaps.js - adding a click function for each marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the [Gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) api in a little project I'm building and struggling with adding click events within a for loop. Here's the code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        var entryTime = data[i].datetime;
        map.addMarker({
            lat: data[i].lat,
            lng: data[i].lng,
            click: function(){
                alert(entryTime);
            }
        });
}
```

However, when clicking the markers I always get the last data element. How can I bind this function to each marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The `entryTime` variable is defined and changed outside the click handler; and when the click handler is fired it will alert the last value assigned to `entryTime`.

One solution is to create a closure in order to create a copy of variables and their values at the time the closure was created.

```
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    map.addMarker({
        lat: data[i].lat,
        lng: data[i].lng,
        click: (function (t) {
            return function () {
                alert(t);
            };
        })(data[i].datetime)
    });
}
```

The details [are explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552941/how-does-a-function-in-a-loop-which-returns-another-function-work).