# Values of variable created in 'for loop' with 'let' inside inner function differs from values of same variable created with 'var'

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, var, let

In the example code from ['let' keyword javascript reference @ Mozilla Developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) from section *Cleaner code in inner functions*:

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let item = document.createElement("li");
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item " + i));

  item.onclick = function (ev) {
    console.log("Item " + i + " is clicked.");
  };
  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

This code's description from underneath the sample states, that *[...]Note that it does not work as intended if you replace let with var, since all of the inner functions would then return the same final value of i: 6[...]*.
I've checked this in webconsole, instead of #list (which I couldn't find in this document) I've targeted *#quick-links ol*, so `var list = document.getElementById("quick-links").children[1];`.

During first test, I pasted into js console opened for that document this sample, with changed target element - so *#quick-links ol* and run.

Result was seen at the bottom of left sidebar, **SEE ALSO** quick links.
When clicked on dom element Item *x*, event script put text "Item *x* was clicked".

Second test, instead of *let* used *var*, and same event scripts printed text "Item 6 was clicked", no matter what item I've clicked on.

Why such behaviour? I know slightly the difference between *let* and *var*, but why *i* in case of *var* in loop is assigned to inner function only with value 6?

Comment: Because `let` defines a variable with block scope, which is rebound each time through the loop.

Comment: I know it's block scoped, so in this example, during every loop, there's created another *i* variable that exist only inside *for loop* particular scope.

And *i* created using *var* would exist outside *for loop* scope.

But bear in mind that assignment of *item.onclick* is inside for loop, yet when *var* is used, only *6* as a value of *i* is used...

Comment: It looks like I don't understand something, but why during every loop in case of using *var*, there's not used *i* with different value when assigning value to *item.click*?
What docs should I read, that could englighten me?

Comment: Found hint in user's @CMS answer @ [How does a function in a loop (which returns another function) work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1552979/7458546)

Comment: Click event prints out the text with *i* variable's value that was last assigned in particular scope.

So in case *var i*, the last value in scope is 6.

But when used *let i*, for every value assignment to *i* in every loop there was created scope, in which *i* had particular value and onclick event function logged out that particular value.

So when *let i == 3*, this value was particular scope wide, so onclick event could not print out anything other than 3 etc.

Comment: Because with `var`, by the time any of the functions are executed, the loop has completed, and the value of `i` is 6 for all of them.